# ngModelOptions not working in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I have defined the directive `myDirective` in the HTML as follows:

```
<input id="myid" ng-model="myModel" value="{{myModel}}" my-directive dirvalue="3" min="0.5" spinner step="0.2" ng-disabled=" !someFunction()">
```

The directive:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', ['InjectedService',
        function (InjectedService) {
            return {
                require: 'ngModel',
                restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    dirvalue: "="
                },

                link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
                    if (ngModelController.$options === undefined || ngModelController.$options === null) {
                        ngModelController.$options = {
                            updateOn: 'blur',
                            debounce: 3000
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
]);
```

I have debugged the code, and the `ngModelController.$options` gets populated perfectly fine.
But I don't get the requisite behavior, i.e., debounce doesn't work!

Please explain what am I doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rewrite the link function as

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', ['$compile','InjectedService',
  function ($compile, InjectedService) {
   return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
             dirvalue: "="
           },
    priority: 1000,
    compile: function compile(element, attrs) {
        element.attr('ng-model-options', '{updateOn: 'default blur', debounce:{'default': 2000, 'blur': 0}}');
        return {
          pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {  },
          post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {  
            $compile(iElement)(scope);
          }
      };
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have right now should work i.e. the model will update 3 seconds after the blur event.

If you however want to update 3 seconds after the `default` triggers as well, then you should be doing

```
ngModelController.$options = {
    updateOn: 'blur',
    updateOnDefault: true,
    debounce: {
        'blur': 3000,
        'default': 3000
    }
};
```

Comment: Which version of angular are you using by the way? You need 1.3.x or higher.

Comment: @VVK - pretty much, if you want it to update on the default triggers, you set it to `true`. If not, you set it to `false`. Or have I got something wrong? Cheers!

Comment: @potatopeelings The version is 1.2.13 but I have added ngmodelOptions separately. It works fine when used within html: ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default blur', debounce:{'default': 2000, 'blur': 0}}"